# Decimal parse when the thousand separator and decimal separator are the same C#

Tags: c#, currency

I'm aplying globalization to an application, and I have the following problem:

I set en-US as culture by default, then I perform a format in order to show to user the formatted value.

```
string FormattedValue = string.Format("{0:C}", 5000.00); //That returns $5.000.00
```

Then I need convert that value to decimal, and is possible also having a currency symbol, but the headache is with the double "."

```
var DecimalValue = decimal.parse(value,NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol);
```

It throws **"Input string was not in a correct format"**. And I know that is caused by the double "." because when I change the culture for example to en-AU, in that case the formatted value is $5,000.00 and decimal.parse works perfectly. Any idea?

Comment: Something's up - `string FormattedValue = string.Format("{0:C}", 5000.00)` with en-US on my system `== $5,000.00`

Comment: When you format, what are the values of `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator` and `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator`?

Comment: Please show code of setting culture

Comment: You right, I did not set that values, and the application has been using the default values (defined on my PC Region settings), now I'm wondering if is imposible convert to number a currency string that uses the same groupSeparator and decimalSeparator.

Comment: @CSharper Curious, which culture had the same decimal and group separator?

Comment: `CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures).Where(c => c.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator[0] == c.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator[0]).ToList().ForEach(c => Console.WriteLine(c.Name))` prints nothing on my system, what does it do on yours?

Answer (score 0):

At this point with my own tinkering, I'm convinced that something is awry with your system's culture settings. I'm on Win 8.1 x64 with .NET 4.5.1, and:

```
  CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
    .Where(c => c.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator[0] == c.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator[0])
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(c => Console.WriteLine(c.Name));
```

prints nothing on my system.

I believe that you can implement your own implementation of `IFormatProvider`, but I really don't think that would solve your problem.